# How to update the next pointer in place in go list?

Tags: list, pointers, go

I have a node pointer from the list. I want update the value and next pointer with the next node in the list. This is nothing but deletion in place given access to only that pointer.

For example 3 -> 5 -> 8 -> 9
Node to be deleted : 5 (given access to only 5. Assuming previous node is not known)

In this case the value and next pointer of node[8] can be copied to node[5]. I have the following code. It is not removing the element. If I try to access the next pointer using 'next' keyword it is throwing error.

```
package main
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    l := list.New()
    l.PushFront(4)
    l.PushFront(5)
    e4 := l.PushFront(7)
    l.PushFront(6)
    l.PushBack(9)
    res := deleteNode(e4)
    fmt.Println(res)

    for e:=l.Front(); e!=nil;e=e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }

}
//ERROR
func deleteNode(node *list.Element) bool {

    if node == nil || node.Next() == nil {
        return false
    }
    var nextNode *list.Element 
    nextNode := node.next.(*list.Element)
    node.Value = node.Next().Value.(int)
    nextNode = nextNode.next.(*Element)
    return true
}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (first) error you get is:

```
no new variables on left side of :=
```

Because `nextNode` already exists. The problem is with these 2 lines:

```
var nextNode *list.Element 
nextNode := node.next.(*list.Element)
```

In the first line you create the variable `nextNode`. In the second line you use the short assignment `:=` which creates a new variable (specified by the left side) and assigns to it the value on the right side. Just leave out the first line, you only need one of those:

```
nextNode := node.Next()
```

Moreover you cannot read or change the `next` pointer of a node because the `next` pointer is not exported in the `Element` struct (it starts with lowercased letter). So what you try to achieve cannot be done. But you have a function defined for this: [`Remove(e *Element) interface{}`](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List.Remove)

Comment: I see the error. Thanks for notifying this. But my original problem is how to access the next pointer from Element structure. As you said next is not exported. But this variable is available in Element struct. http://golang.org/src/container/list/list.go?s=406:874#L5
So is it not possible to access the pointer?

Comment: @DineshAppavoo Yes, the `next` field is part of the `Element` struct but it is not exported which means it can only be accessed from the package it was defined in. You could go around this restriction with package `unsafe`, but that is not the proper way, fields that are not exported may change in future releases.

Comment: I got it. Is it possible to delete the node in the list by giving access to only the node

Comment: @DineshAppavoo Unfortunately no. `Element` only provides access to previous and next elements and its value. You would need access to the `List` to call its `Remove()` method, and even that takes a value to be removed, not an `Element`.